# Order table by proximity to specific latitude/longitude (using MySQL+PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, latitude-longitude, proximity

MySQL (table)

```
id | url |    lat    |    lng
----------------------------------
1  |  x  | 44.339565 | -101.337891
----------------------------------
2  |  y  | 44.150681 | -101.074219
----------------------------------
3  |  z  | 43.897892 | -100.634766
```

what I want to do now is order the list according to their proximity to (43.834527,-99.140625).

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY proximity DESC");
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
echo $b['url'].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may be interested in checking out the following presentation:

- [Geo/Spatial Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)<sup>1</sup> by [Alexander Rubin](http://www.arubin.org/blog/presentations/)

The author describes how you can use the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) in MySQL to order by proximity and limit your searches to a defined range. He also describes how to avoid a full table scan for such queries, using traditional indexes on the latitude and longitude columns.

---

<sup>1</sup> [PDF Version](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf)