# Sorting by distance in MySQL with spatial analysis functions and data types

Tags: php, mysql, geospatial, eloquent, geo

I'm building a php web app with Laravel 5.5 and I need to display a list of places (eg. stores) sorted by their distance from a user-specified location.
The places will be stored in a MySQL database and should be retrieved as Eloquent ORM model instances.

Doing some research I found many posts and questions on this topic (presenting different solutions), but, having very little experience with databases and geolocation/geospatial analysis, they mostly confused me, and I'd like to know what approach to follow and what are the best practices in this case.

Most answers I read suggest using the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance#Computational_formulas) or the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) in the SQL query, which would look something like (example taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16465874/2382892)):

```
$sf = 3.14159 / 180; // scaling factor
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table 
    WHERE lon BETWEEN '$minLon' AND '$maxLon' 
      AND lat BETWEEN '$minLat' AND '$maxLat'
    ORDER BY ACOS(SIN(lat*$sf)*SIN($lat*$sf) + COS(lat*$sf)*COS($lat*$sf)*COS((lon-$lon)*$sf))";
```

[This post](http://jonisalonen.com/2014/computing-distance-between-coordinates-can-be-simple-and-fast/) points out the fact that, over short distances, assuming the Earth flat and computing a simple euclidean distance is a good approximation and is faster than using the haversine formula.
Since I only need to sort places **within a single city** at a time, this seems to be a good solution.

However, most of these posts and SO answers are a few years old and I was wondering if there is now (MySQL 5.7) a better solution.

For example, none of those post use any of MySQL “Spatial Analysis Functions”, like [`ST_Distance_Sphere`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) and [`ST_Distance`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-distance) which seem to be exactly for that purpose.
Is there any reason (eg. performance, precision) **not** to use these functions instead of writing the formula in the query? (I don't know which algorithm is internally used for these functions)

I also don't know how I should store the coordinates of each place.
Most of the examples I've seen assume the coordinates to be stored in separate `lat`, `lon` columns as doubles or as `FLOAT(10,6)` (as in [this example by google](https://developers.google.com/maps/solutions/store-locator/clothing-store-locator)), but also MySQL `POINT` data type seems appropriate for storing geographic coordinates.
What are the pros and cons of these two approaches?

How can indexes be used to speed up these kind of queries? For example I've read about [“spatial indexes”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-indexes.html), but I think they can only be used for limiting the results with something like `MBRContains()`, not to actually order the results by distance.

So, **how should I store the coordinates of places and how should I query them to be ordered by distance?**

Comment: Don't roll your own GIS functions if you can avoid it, use the spatial extensions. Many of those questions pre-date that extension becoming popular and/or existing. If you're doing a lot of GIS-type work you may find MySQL is a little weak and Postgres with [PostGIS](https://postgis.net) works much better.

Comment: Out of interest, how many points do you have? Do you need only closest n?  In my experience the approach to this kind of application depends very heavily of these questions. There are quite a few indexing and caching techniques for this. I have got 60000+ property searches under 5ms, but these weren't pure MySQL solutions - so I can't really help here :)

Answer (score 5):

Other than the ST_Distance_Sphere, 5.7 does not bring anything extra to the table. (SPATIAL was already implemented.)

For 'thousands' of points, the code you have is probably the best.  Include

```
INDEX(lat, lng),
INDEX(lng, lat)
```

And I would not worry about the curvature of the earth unless you are stretching thousands of miles (kms).  Even then the code and that function should be good enough.

Do not use `FLOAT(m,n)`, use only `FLOAT`.  The link below gives the precision available to `FLOAT` and other representations.

If you have so many points that you can't cache the table and its indexes entirely (many millions of points), you could use [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) , which uses a couple of tricks to avoid lengthy scans like the above solution.  Because of `PARTITION` limitations, lat/lng are represented as scaled integers.  (But that is easy enough to convert in the input/output.)  The earth's curvature, poles, and dateline are all handled.

Comment: I think GCDist is the right answer, so up-voting Rick. Another related problem is GC distance vs. driving distance.  For example, Northport, NY and Darien, CT are about 13 miles apart, but, being separated by the Long Island Sound, the driving distance is 66 miles, including stretches through Queens and the Bronx.  Its probably overkill for your requirements, but using the GC distance as a screen, and then using a map tool such as [this](https://www.freemaptools.com/distance-between-usa-zip-codes.htm) to convert the distances to driving distance and re-sort would give the best results.

Comment: @wordragon - You can probably get "driving distance" through some API from Google.  But I suspect it does not scale well, at least not this year.  Next, you will want "driving time".  Google does a better job than my car's Nav system -- because of dealing with current traffic situations.

Comment: I wasn't proposing doing that for thousands of points.  In a typical "store-finder" app which looks for locations within, say 25 miles, you could use GCDist to get the locations within 25 miles (presumably not very many), then calculate the driving distance of the results, throwing out any > 25 miles, and sorting the remainder.  Most apps of that type offer you some kind of map display, so you may already be doing half of the job already.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your answer. I posted an answer too based on my working solution which I found after posting this bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a table that has lat & long associate with zip codes that I found.  I use the haversine formula to find all zipcodes within a certain range.  I then use that list of zip codes that are returned from that query and find all business with those zip codes.  Maybe that solution will work for you.  It was pretty easy to implement. This also eliminates you having to know the lat and long for the each business as long as you know the zip code.

Comment: That might be a nice solution, but OP stated "_Since I only need to sort places within a single city at a time_" so it looks to me that ZIP codes won't be a great help here

Comment: I must have overlooked that part.  In that case he just needs to query the stores by city, probably narrowing down the results significantly, then running the haversine formula from there.  He will have to know the lat and long for each business.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` or `MBRContains` to get distance between points or points within a bound - much faster than doing Haversine formula which can't use indices and is not built for querying distances and because MySql is slow with range queries. Refer [mysql documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)

Haversine formula is probably good for small applications and most of the older answer refer to that solution because older versions of MySql innodb did not have spatial indexes.

The broad method of doing it is as follows - the below is from my working code in Java - hope you can tailor it for PHP as per your needs

1. First **save the incoming data as a Point in database** (Do note that the coordinate formula uses longitude, latitude  convention)

   ```
       GeometryFactory factory = new GeometryFactory();
       Point point = factory.createPoint(new Coordinate(officeDto.getLongitude(), officeDto.getLatitude()));//IMP:Longitude,Latitude
       officeDb.setLocation(point);
   ```
2. **Create Spatial Indexes** using the following in mysql

   > CREATE SPATIAL INDEX location ON office (location);

You might get the error *"All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL"*. That is because spatial indexes can only be created if the field is NOT NULL - in such a case convert the field to non-null

3. Finally, call the custom function ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE from your code as follows.

   ```
   SELECT st_distance_sphere( office.getLocation ,  project.getLocation) 
    as distance FROM ....
   ```

Note: office.getLocation and project.getLocation both return POINT types. Native SQL method is as below from documentation

```
ST_Distance_Sphere(g1, g2 [, radius])
```

which returns the mimimum spherical distance between two points and/or multipoints on a sphere, in meters, or NULL if any geometry argument is NULL or empty.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. You should always use any spatial function over any manual math. Doing math in the order by will void using indexes, can't use an index if you must calculate the value first before sorting.